# Laravel Mix 6 ver upgrade error inpackage.json

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-mix

My task is to upgrade package.json in Laravel. I haven't had any problems using Laravel-Mix 5 ver until now, but I got the following error after switching to 6 ver.

> error: unknown option '--env.mixfile=webpack.admin.mix' error Command
> failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command. error: unknown option '--env.mixfile=webpack.client.mix'
> error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
> https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
> command.

Perhaps the way "Scripts" is written may have changed. My Scripts in Package.json as below.  Webpack.mix.js is divided by authority.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn run-p dev:admin dev:client dev:sp",
    "dev:admin": "NODE_ENV=local yarn development -- --env.mixfile=webpack.admin.mix",
    "dev:client": "NODE_ENV=local yarn development -- --env.mixfile=webpack.client.mix",
    "dev:sp": "NODE_ENV=local yarn development -- --env.mixfile=webpack.sp.mix",
    ...
```

My env

- PHP: 7.4.29
- Laravel :8.76.2
- Yarn: 1.22.5
- Node: 16.14.2
- Laravel Mix: 6.0.43

Already tried

- Remake node_modules.
- Yarn cache clear.
- Deleted "-- --" in Scripts then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the `development` script run?

In a default laravel mix package.json its `mix`. If that's the case you could try the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "yarn run-p dev:admin dev:client dev:sp",
    "dev:admin": "mix --mix-config=webpack.admin.mix.js",
    "dev:client": "mix --mix-config=webpack.client.mix.js",
    "dev:sp": "mix --mix-config=webpack.sp.mix.js",
    ...
```